# Git Pushing a branch to heroku

Tags: git, heroku

I am very new to git but I need to use it for one of my projects. A few days ago I created a local branch for the project and started working on (the new branch) it locally. Now I want to be able to push this new branch of the project to heroku.

I saw that the way to do it is to

```
git push heroku branchname
```

I tried doing that but I only get

```
Everything up-to-date
```

So I assume it was already pushed to heroku and checked it out only to find out that nothing changed. The new features are missing still. The two local branches share the same heroku's repository.

Comment: Did you `commit` your changes before you ran `push`?

Comment: (You can double-check by using `git log` and seeing if there is a listing for your changes there.)

Comment: @eldarerathis
i did "git commit -m "msg"" before I ran push

@Amber I saw the log and it was committed but i did not see the push in there. I tried committing and I only get
"# On branch fbintegrate
nothing to commit (working directory clean)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so I got the answer and this is the answer from heroku

"Branches pushed to Heroku other than “master” will be ignored. If you’re working out of another branch locally, you should either merge to master before pushing, or always specify the branch name to push to, as in “git push heroku master”.

Comment: worth noting here how to push non master branches is really "git push heroku localbranch:master"  (where heroku is the git remote path to your heroku app and localbranch is the one you want to push)